# js object constructer with imgage prototype

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put image as one of object's prototype.

What am i missing here?

This is my code:

```
function test(prot1, prot2) {
  this.par1 = prot1;
  this.par2 = prot2;
}
var test1 = new test("text", "image.jpg");
document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = "<img src='test1.par2' alt='test1.par1' class='image' />";
```

Comment: I recommend using string concatenation `'src="' + test1.par1 +'"'`, or template literals `\`src="${test1.par}"\``.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you. Now, i know the grammar for this operation too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used only strings, but you need to evaluate the object.

With **ES6** you can use [**template literals**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = `<img src='${test1.par2}' alt='${test1.par1}' class='image' />`;
```

With lower versions you can use string concatenations

```
document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = "<img src=" + test1.par2 + "alt=" + test1.par1 + " class='image' />";
```

Comment: thank you. now, i know the grammar for this operation too.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you cannot simply type the variables inside the string and expect them to be evaluated. This doesn't work.

You need to concatenate them in order to be treated as variables and not only as part of the string:

```
document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = "<img src=" + test1.par2 + "alt=" + test1.par1 + " class='image' />";
```

Or if your environment supports ES6, you can use string literals:

```
document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = `<img src=${test1.par2} alt=${test1.par1} class='image' />`;
```

More info on the latter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: thank you. now, i know the grammar for this operation too.